# Redux - approach to modifying state with actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Hello i'm trying to create some kind of lottery and i'm wondering which approach of modifying state by actions payload should be used.

Let's say i have state

```
type initialCartState = {
    productsFromPreviousSession: Product[]
    selectedProduct: Product
    balance: number,
    productsInCart: Product[]
}
```

and our reducer looks like

```
const reducers = {
 addProduct(state, action) => {
    state.products.push(state.action.payload.product)
 },
 addProductsFromPreviousSession(state, action) => {
    state.products.push(...state.productsFromPreviousSession)
 },
}
```

And i noticed i used completely two different approaches with these two types cuz in my component it looks like

```
const component = () => {
   const selectedProduct = useSelector(state => state.cart.selectedProduct);
   const availableBalance = useSelector(state => state.cart.balance - sum(state.cart.products, 'price'));
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
   const sumOfProductsFromPreviousSession = useSelector(state => sum(state.cart.products,'price'))

   return (
       <div> 
           <div onClick={() => {
              if((balance - selectedProduct.price) > 0) {
                 dispatch(cartActions.addProduct(selectedProduct))
              }
           }}/>
           <div onClick={() => {
              if((balance - sumOfProductsFromPreviousSession) > 0) {
                 dispatch(cartActions. addProductsFromPreviousSession())
              }
           }}/>
       </div>
   )
}
```

There are two different types of handling actions, in addProduct i used selector and pass value in action payload. In Add products from previous session we rely on state inside reducer (Also have middleware for purpose of saving in localStorage, but there i used store.getState()). Which kind of approach is correct ?

Also how it will change when we move balance to another reducer, and then we will not have access to that i cartReducer?

I saw there are bunch of examples on counter when increment and decrement rely on current reducerState and there are actions without payload, but there is no validation which is used in my example.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches can be used. Basically, if you need to show state data in UI or other parts of processes, you should read with `selector`. This way, changes inside the store can be reflected in the components reactively.

In your case, you are just updating the state value with currently available data from the state. So, you can dispatch action without payload.

In your example, even though you pass the payload from `onClick` event, you are still reading the value from the state itself.